# Rails Time Select, rearrange components

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, time, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The default rails datetime form builder provides the following form elements as select boxes...

```
[YYYY] [MONTH] [DD] - [HH]:[MM]
```

... in 24 hour time.

I would like to present my users with:

```
[MON.] [DD] [YYYY] - [HH]:[MM] [AM/PM]
```

How do you do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`datetime_select` helper has lots of different options. I never bothered to remember them all so I use [this apidock page](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select) as a reference (datetime_select and date_select have similar options).

In you case, you'll need to set `:order` array, `:ampm` to true, etc.

Edit: ok, I actually bothered to write the option hash you'll need:

```
date_select("question", "answered_at", :ampm => true, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :use_short_month  => true)
```

Comment: This works, with one oddity... The select boxes generated for time say, for instance [3PM]:[30] instead of [3]:[30] [PM]. Any idea how to make AM/PM a field on the end rather than embedded in the hour?

Comment: As you can see from :ampm option source code in Ruby on Rails ( https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/343 ), there's no way to customize it any further. Also, there are no other datetime_select AM/PM-related options (:ampm itself was added to core just 6 months ago). So, you should either use it as is or write your own datetime select helper.